# I am trying to insert a newline AND make all of the characters uppercase in a Python file. How can I do this without duplcate lines

Tags: python

```
fname = raw_input("Enter filename:")

fh = open("words.txt", "r")

count = 0
for line in fh:
    print line.strip()
    print line.upper()
    count = count + 1
```

Comment: You are printing twice and hence the duplicates? How about `print line.strip().upper()` instead?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with one line of code:

```
print line.strip().upper()
```

Example:

```
>>> lines = ['This is a line    ', 
    '   this IS another LInE', 
    '   spaces!   ', 
    'nospaces', 
    'no leading or trailing spaces'
]
>>> for line in lines:
...     print line.strip().upper()
...
THIS IS A LINE
THIS IS ANOTHER LINE
SPACES!
NOSPACES
NO LEADING OR TRAILING SPACES
```

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you. I didn't realize you could put them both together as one statement. I'm a newbie as you can see. Thanks again.